# Why does np.median() return multiple rows?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which has 100 rows and 16026 columns. I have to find the median of every column. So median for every column will be calculated from 100 observations (100 rows in this case). I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
for category in categories:
    indices = np.random.randint(0, len(os.listdir(filepath + category)) - 1, 100)
    tempArray = X_train[indices, ]
    medArray = np.median(tempArray, axis=0)
    print(medArray.shape)
```

And here's the output that I get:

```
(100, 16026)
(100, 16026)
(100, 16026)
(100, 16026)
```

My question is - why is the shape of `medArray` 100*16026 and not 1*16026? Because I am calculating the median of every column, I would expect only one row with 16026 columns. What am I missing here?

Please note that `X_train` is a sparse matrix.

```
X_train.shape
```

output:

```
(2034, 16026)
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

The above problem has been solved by `toarray()` function.

```
tempArray = X_train[indices, ].toarray()
```

**I also figured that I was being stupid and also including all the zeroes in my median calculation and that's why I was getting 0 as the median all the time. Is there an easy way of calculating the median by removing/ignoring the zeroes across all the columns?**

Comment: sorry to misread your question, what's your `tempArray.shape`?

Comment: tempArray.shape = (100,16026)

Comment: do you want to get the median on the dense array (0s included)?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I think you have a really god point here. In the madness of battling with numpy, I think I forgot the basics of statistics and I think I was including the zeroes as well in the calculation of median. No wonder I was getting all zeroes, I guess it was calculating the median for every column correctly, which happened to be zero. I would want to exclude zeroes in order to calculate the median.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this. I used masked arrays and the following code:

```
 sample = [] 
    sample_size = 50
    idx = matplotlib.mlab.find(newsgroups_train.target==i)
    random_index = []
    for j in range(sample_size):
        random_index.append(randrange(0,len(idx)-1)) 

y = np.ma.masked_where(X_train[sample[0]].toarray() == 0, X_train[sample[0]].toarray())
    medArray = np.ma.median(y, axis=0).filled(0)
    print '============median ' + newsgroups_train.target_names[i] + '============='
    for k,word in enumerate(np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names())[np.argsort(medArray)[::-1][0:10]]):
        print word + ':' + str(np.sort(medArray)[::-1][k])
```

This gave me the median ignoring zeros.

Answer (score 1):

That's really strange, I think you should get `(16026,)`, are we missing something here:

```
In [241]:

X_train=np.random.random((1000,16026)) #1000 can be any int.
indices = np.random.randint(0, 60, 100) #60 can be any int.
tempArray = X_train[indices, ]
medArray = np.median(tempArray, axis=0)
print(medArray.shape)

(16026,)
```

And the only way you can get a `2d array` result is:

```
In [243]:

X_train=np.random.random((100,2,16026))
indices = np.random.randint(0, 60, 100)
tempArray = X_train[indices, ]
medArray = np.median(tempArray, axis=0)
print(medArray.shape)


(2, 16026)
```

When you have a `3d array` input.

When it is a `sparse` `array`, a dumb way to get around this might be:

```
In [319]:

X_train = sparse.rand(112, 16026, 0.5, 'csr') #just make up a random sparse array
indices = np.random.randint(0, 60, 100)
tempArray = X_train[indices, ]
medArray = np.median(tempArray.toarray(), axis=0)
print(medArray.shape)
(16026,)
```

`.toarray()` might also go to the 3rd line instead. But either way, this means the `0`'s are also counted as @zhangxaochen pointed out.

Out of ideas, there may be better explanations for it.

Comment: The result of your 2d array makes sense. I am trying to do exactly the same thing but somehow my output gives me 100*16026.

Comment: Oh, actually, since now you mentioned it is a `sparse`, things are now different. Which format is it? `csc`?

Comment: It is actually csr, I am not sure what's that supposed to mean though !

Comment: I highly suspect it has to do with the structure of `sparse` `array` `X_train`. If just input a random array, say,`np.median(sparse.rand(5,5,0.6,'csr')[1,], axis=0)`, I get `IndexError: axis 0 out of bounds (0)`

Comment: I tried using toarray() as well but got incorrect results primarily due to my stupidity of including zeroes in the median calculation. I will do the whole thing again without including zeroes this time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that NumPy doesn't recognize sparse matrices as arrays or array-like objects. For example, calling `asanyarray` on a sparse matrix returns a 0D array whose one element is the original sparse matrix:

```
In [8]: numpy.asanyarray(scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
Out[8]:
array(<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>, dtype=object)
```

Like most of NumPy, `numpy.median` relies on having an array or array-like object as input. The routines it relies on, particularly `sort`, won't understand what they're looking at if you give it a sparse matrix.

Comment: Shouldn't it mean that `np.median(xxxxx, axis=0)` will result in `IndexError: axis 0 out of bounds (0)`? OP somehow didn't get that exception.

Comment: @CTZhu: You'd think so, but `sort` doesn't seem to throw an error for out-of-bounds axes when the input is 0D or 1D. I suspect it assumes all possible axis values are equivalent for 0D and 1D arrays and doesn't bother to look at the axis value specified.

Comment: To clear this, I used the following code: tempArray[0,np.nonzero(tempArray[0])].tolist() . This coverts my tempArray into a normal python list. Now if I calculate median for every column on tempArray, in practice it should work out, but it actually doesn't. When I run the following code to calculate the median: print np.nonzero(np.median(tempArray)), I receive a blank array and I am 100% sure that I have values in tempArray.

Comment: @Patthebug: If your data is sparse, the median of any given row is probably 0. Could that be the cause?

Comment: @user2357112 -  I think you have a really god point here. In the madness of battling with numpy, I think I forgot the basics of statistics and I think I was including the zeroes as well in the calculation of median. No wonder I was getting all zeroes, I guess it was calculating the median for every column correctly, which happened to be zero. I would want to exclude zeroes in order to calculate the median.